# Adding own files/packages to a custom anaconda environment

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables, anaconda, python-import, pythonpath

I have a custom anaconda environment which I am using to run a program which is dependent on files in another directory. How do I add these files to the environment like I would do with a system interpreter by adding the paths to PYTHONPATH variable in system variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not need to add the custom files to the virtual environment configuration. I was using the Pycharm Python editor and found a better workaround by adding the paths to the selected interpreter (which in this case was the interpreter for the virtual python environment that I was using).

1. Go to `File` —>`Settings`—> `Project: Project name`—>`Project Interpreter`
2. Next to the project interpreter, click the little gear icon.
3. Click on `Show all.` A window should pop-up.
4. On the right side of the window, there’s a toolbar containing 5 options starting with the plus icon.
5. Click on the last icon with the file symbol. Another window should open.
6. Here click on the plus symbol on the top right toolbar.
7. Go to the directory that you want to include to use in your code and click Ok to add them to the interpreter path.
8. Repeat for any other directories or files that you may need to have.

This solution with Pycharm worked out pretty well for me since I only needed to reference those files on my computer for that particular project.